# Openflow project build fail on Mac OS in OMNET++ 5.6.2

Tags: macos, build, omnet++, inet, openflow

I was trying for building [this openflow project](https://github.com/CoRE-RG/OpenFlow) in OMNeT++ and INET framework and faced with the problem. My setup:

1. Mac OS Big Sur 11.5.2;
2. OMNet++ 5.6.2;
3. INET framework 3.6.6.
4. Openflow [build toolchain setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Z5P.png) is default.

INET building was complete, but openflow building crashes with this error:
`./openflow/openflow/controller/Switch_Info.h:8:17: error: expected namespace name`
`using namespace __gnu_cxx;`

On Win 10 via bootcamp with the same setup openflow building was success.
What am I doing wrong with that?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the probelem by using [Docker container engine and XQuartz](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a386-CiQeHE).

BTW it's working when `using namespace __gnu_cxx;` line is commented in "Switch_Info.h", "LLDPMibGraph.h", "LLDPMib.h", "Flow_Table.h", "Flow_Table_Entry.h" files